# What does this shell script mean? mysqld_safe --user=mysql &

Tags: shell

`mysqld_safe --user=mysql &`  was used to startup mysql. I want to know how does shell script receive parameter like `--user=mysql`.

And what does `&` signal mean here?

Comment: `&` means it's working in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` means that the process will be working on background.

From `man bash`:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

In practice, it means that you can launch the `mysqld_safe --user=mysql` command and keep working on that terminal.

#### Test

```
$ sleep 5
                ### 5 seconds
$ 


$ sleep 5 &
[1] 4009
$ jobs          ### shows current background processes
[1]+  Running                 sleep 5 &
$ 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 5
$
```